# ncurses inchstr function not working as intended?

Tags: c++11, ncurses, curses

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <fstream>

int main(){

    initscr();
    mvwprintw(stdscr, 1,1, "hello world");
    wmove(stdscr, 1,1);

    chtype* p = 0;
    int n = 0;
    n = winchstr(stdscr, p);

    std::ofstream test("test.txt");

    test << n << " " << (p == nullptr);

    endwin();

}
```

In the above I print `hello world`, move the cursor back to the start of the sentence, and attempt to store the contents of what is on screen in to `p` using `winchstr`. Except in the file `test.txt` I see only the output `-1 1` suggesting `p` was unchanged and `ERR` (i.e. -1) was returned, as the [documentation](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/doc/PDCurses.txt) describes:

> int winchstr(WINDOW *win, chtype *ch);
>
> Description:
>       These routines read a chtype or cchar_t string from the window, 
>       starting at the current or specified position, and ending at the 
>       right margin, or after n elements, whichever is less.
>
> Return Value:
>       All functions return the number of elements read, or ERR on 
>       error.

Have I misunderstood the documentation? The contents of the line starting at `hello world` should be stored in the location pointed to by `p` after using `winchstr`  shouldn't it? Why is it returning error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location `p` is a null pointer; ncurses will probably see that, and refuse to use it.  The manual page says

> No  error  conditions are defined.  If the *chstr* parameter
>   is null, no data is returned, and the return value is  zero.

If you use `winchstr`, with a non-null pointer, ncurses will (have to) assume you provide enough space for the result.  Use [`winchnstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inchstr.3x.html) to specify the size.

Comment: Thankyou. I had assumed it took the pointer by reference and changed the pointer location to point to what I wanted. (I know it doesn't say it takes it by reference, but curses' `getyx` function doesn't either yet it changes the two passed integers).